# Doorbell transformer identification

Tags: electrical

I want to install a doorbell camera (house was built in 1908).
Is this the transformer?[image]

Comment: Perhaps a photo from the side might help. From the front, it just looks like a block for screw connections, e.g., to front and side buttons.

Comment: Even if it is, I would probably want a newer one.  It looks more like a lightening resistor for telephone system.  Modern doorbell cameras usually take more power than old doorbells.

Answer (score 1):

No. This is a lightning arrester for a telephone company land line.

What you are looking for looks something like this (Home Depot):
[image]

It may be mounted directly to an electrical box, in which case, the wires may be hidden inside the box but the screw terminals will be exposed.

Comment: They also sometimes are installed inside a largish junction box, or the fuse/breaker enclosure itself, or fastened to some random framing member in the attic/basement/crawlspace far from any box, or on the furnace/ductwork in the case of old knob&tube wiring.

Comment: Thanks.  I was afraid it had to do with the phone. I now think the transformer must be in the "basement" (crawlspace) which I was hoping to avoid.